# How to group and calculate value array when found same two keys array

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

I have php array like this:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ([electronics] => TV [condition] => GOOD [1] => 100 [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => [10] => ) 
[1] => Array ([electronics] => TV [condition] => NOTGOOD [1] => 50 [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => [10] => ) 
[2] => Array ([electronics] => AC [condition] => GOOD [1] => 200 [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => [10] => ) 
[3] => Array ([electronics] => TV [condition] => GOOD [1] => 50 [2] => 30 [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => [10] => ) 
[4] => Array ([electronics] => AC [condition] => GOOD [1] => 50 [2] => 30 [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => [10] => ) 
)
```

Then I want to group and calculation by [electronics] and [condition].
(calculated when found same [electronics] and [condition] in that array).
And the result I want like this:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ([electronics] => TV [condition] => GOOD [1] => 150 [2] => 30 [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => [10] => ) 
[1] => Array ([electronics] => TV [condition] => NOTGOOD [1] => 50 [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => [10] => ) 
[2] => Array ([electronics] => AC [condition] => GOOD [1] => 250 [2] => 30 [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] => [9] => [10] => ) 
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be one way to do it:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($arrays as $array) {
    $key = $array['electronics'] . $array['condition'];
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        if (is_numeric($k)) {
            $result[$key][$k] += $v;
        } else {
            $result[$key][$k] = $v;
        }
    }
}

$result = array_values($result);
```

Comment: wow, thank you very much. it's work. but still some error in line $result[$key][$k] += $v;
it should be replaced using $result2[$key][$k] = isset($result2[$key][$k]) ? $result2[$key][$k] + $v : $v;

Comment: Yeah, you may get warnings, I thought that PHP would probably use a default value of 0 if that key wasn't yet present.